# Allow external users without an Office 365 account to access areas of my wiki

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, sharepoint-permissions

I want to get a link that I can share with my customers.

This link should enable external users to access my site. These users don't have an Office 365 account and don't want to create/use one. They don't want to have to register anywhere, they just want to get to the Wiki with a link in their web browser. There are certain document libraries which they should be able to access. The entire access should only authorize the users to view the documents, nothing else.

- Do I have to create SubSites? Is this a good idea?
- Or should I create a hub site and connect sites to this?

What is the concrete way to implement my request?

Comment: It isn't very clear exactly what you want to do. Can you edit your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to accomplish? Do you want to let specific customers view specific articles, but not anyone else, for instance? Or let all customers view certain articles, while keeping other articles private? Do these customers already have access to your SharePoint/Active Directory structure?

Comment: @CarlF I made my question more specific, is this now ok?

Comment: Yes, that is much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The external sharing features of SharePoint Online let users in your organization share content with people outside the organization (such as partners, vendors, clients, or customers).  You can also use external sharing to share between licensed users on multiple Office 365 subscriptions if your organization has more than one subscription.

SharePoint Online has external sharing settings at both the organization level and the site level (previously called the "site collection" level). To allow external sharing on any site, you must allow it at the organization level. You can then restrict external sharing for other sites. If a site's external sharing option and the organization-level sharing option don't match, the most restrictive value will always be applied.

Whichever option you choose at the organization or site level, the more restrictive functionality is still available. For example, if you choose to allow sharing using "Anyone" links (previously called "shareable" links or "anonymous access" links), users can still share with guests who sign in, and with internal users.

Kindly have a look at the below links to more about external sharing,

1. [External sharing overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)
2. [Secure external sharing recipient experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new-in-sharing-in-targeted-release?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fwhat-s-new-in-sharing-in-targeted-release-cc78357c-6d48-499c-9cc7-dae447d0d391)
3. [External Sharing in SharePoint Online: Key Facts & Best Practices](https://www.syskit.com/blog/external-sharing-in-sharepoint-online/)
4. [The ultimate guide to Office 365 external sharing](https://sharegate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-deal-with-office-365-external-sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the external Sharing which will allow you to share the site with users who are not part of Office365. Refer the following article which details on how external sharing works:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off